# How to plot figure using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, figure

I have the following the data.

```
 Variables  Cropland Forest  Shrub   Urban   Water  Baresoil MeanDecreaseAccuaracy MeanDecreaseGini
 band1       23.152  14.686  30.012  26.866  12.976    9.767                33.991          142.946
 band2       23.359  19.116  30.077  23.961  14.120   11.793                32.729          165.892
 band3       24.835  21.590  17.912  18.490  14.806   23.961                32.254          169.372
 band4       25.709  34.052  20.737  23.170  13.894   25.297                36.721          209.631
 band5       20.158  29.281  24.762  25.535  18.537   14.182                36.525          141.047
 band6       32.447  25.134  24.800  35.590  22.485   16.168                40.496          232.536
 band7       26.135  41.411  36.753  26.935  19.767    9.806                39.886          226.782
 band8        2.460   1.930   1.872  -0.434  -0.088    4.831                 4.315            5.334
```

Now, I want to use these data to plot the following figure

[image: following figure].

Comment: You should do some of your own work. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: After the edit, the question has not improved to a point where I would want to re-open it. Sorry. Please include a [MCVE](/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that.I did some work for my figure,but it can not work well.

Answer (score 2):

The plot you are referring to was not made using `ggplot2`, but using `lattice` library. You can find some examples of using `lattice` on [Quick-R website](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html). Below I quote the code example provided on this site and the output plot:

```
library(lattice)
attach(mtcars)

gear.f<-factor(gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
   labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears"))
cyl.f <-factor(cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
   labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

bwplot(cyl.f~mpg|gear.f,
   ylab="Cylinders", xlab="Miles per Gallon",
   main="Mileage by Cylinders and Gears",
   layout=(c(1,3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear downvoter -- why -1 ?

Comment: Just a random guess (down voting motives can be pretty random), but some people don't like it when terrible questions are rewarded with good answers. They feel it encourages more people to ask terrible questions.